# Как избавиться от большого количества запросов к бд, при попытке вытянуть связи через expand в Yii2?

Tags: php, sql, yii2, relation, оптимизация-запросов

Разрабатываю RESTful API на фреймворке Yii2. На данный момент делаю вторую версию API `v2`. Задача следующая:

**Сократить количество запросов к бд, при выборке.**

Отправляется запрос на URL: `api.com/v2/indicators&expand=tickers`.

В `expand` я передаю связи, которые хочу вытянуть. Вообще в `expand` можно предать до 20 связей. Данных в базе достаточно много, и поэтому `Yii2` делает **очень много** запросов, для того чтобы получить все `tickers` для `indicators`.
Связь `MANY_TO_MANY`.

Пример: В базе есть 300 индикаторов, у каждого индикатора есть много тикеров. Связь идет через `junction table`, в модели `Indicator` выглядит так:

```php
public function getTickers(): ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticker::class, ['id' => 'tickerId'])
        ->viaTable(RelationIndicatorTicker::tableName(), ['indicatorId' => 'id']);
}
```

Используется дефолтный `ActiveController` и его дефолтный `IndexAction`. Связи все тянет правильно, но делает примерно **300*20 = 6000** запросов, если у каждого индикатора будет по 20 тикеров(что так и есть).

Сейчас `Yii2` в базу делает такие пустые запросы, которые исполняются по 6000 раз:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ticker` WHERE 0=1
```

Вот скрин из NeorProfiler
[image: Neor Profiler]

Видно что у `indicator` с `id = 8` есть два тикера с `id IN(40, 51)`. Т.е. все остальные запросы просто сплошной мусор. Как от этого можно избавиться? Есть ли какие-то варианты переопределить `expand`?

---

Пробовал я еще переопределять дефолтный `IndexAction`, и там переопределял `prepareDataProvider`, писал свой метод для этого в котором получал:

```php
$query = Indicator::find();

$expand = Yii::$app->getRequest->getQueryParam('expand');
$expand = explode(',', $expand);

foreach($expand as $relationName) {
    //  тут можно сделать проверку на реляцию, но сейчас не суть
    $query = $query->joinWith($relationName);
}
```

Таким способом все работало и в базе не было "мусора", и вместо 6000 запросов было всего 3, **разница очень большая**. Есть ли какие-то другие, более "элегантные" способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: where 0=1 это какой-то валидатор делает. Помню была такая проблема, удалил правило из rules в модели и запросы перестали появляться.

Comment: Думаю что дело не в валидаторе, потому что если использовать через `->with()` то таких вот лишних запросов нет. Он пытается подставить значение, скорее всего вместо `id` ставит `false` в php, а в базе это `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

return $this->hasMany(Ticker::class, ['id' => 'tickerId'])
        ->with('ticker') // по идее эта строчка должна помочь - это жадный запрос
        ->viaTable(RelationIndicatorTicker::tableName(), ['indicatorId' => 'id']);
```

Comment: К сожалению вы не правы( Потому что вы вызываете `->with()` от класса `Ticker`, у которого нет реляции `tickers`, которая относится к `Indicator`.

Comment: значит with() нужно добаить в Indicators::find() переопределив это в дата провайдере. https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/#lazy-eager-loading

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, добавить `with()` к `ActiveQuery` instance, но будет костыль, потому что `expand` поле динамическое и в нем может быть прописано не название реляции, а название, к примеру, несуществующей, в таком случае должно быть пропущено и вызваны все остальные валидные.